# Python language API

Tags: python, reference, documentation, python-2.x

I'm starting with Python coming from java.

I was wondering if there exists something similar to JavaDoc API where I can find the class, its methods and and example of how to use it.

I've found very helpul to use *help( thing )* from the Python ( command line )

I have found this also:

http://docs.python.org/2/

https://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html

But it seems to help when you already have the class name  you are looking for. In JavaDoc API I have all the classes so if I need something I scroll down to  a class that "sounds like" what I need. Or some times I just browse all the classes to see what they do, and when I need a feature my brain recalls me   *We saw something similar in the javadoc remember!?*

But I don't seem to find the similar in Python ( yet ) and that why I'm posting this questin.

BTW I know that I would eventually will read this:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/

But, well, I think it is not today.

Comment: Closed. pydoc and pydocgui.pyw are the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html)?

I'm not sure if you're looking for something more sophisticated, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The standard python library is fairly well documented. Try jumping into python and importing a module say "os" and running:

```
import os   
help(os)
```

This reads the doc strings on each of the items in the module and displays it. This is exactly what pydoc will do too.

EDIT: [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) is probably exactly what you're looking for:

Comment: Yeap, that's what I'm using right now as I said. But Is there a way to  browse all the standard classes , like in:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/

No would be an acceptable answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.python.org/py-modindex.html) is a list of all the modules in Python, not sure if that's what you're really after.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded Python 2.5 from Python.org and It does not contains pydoc.

```
Directorio de C:\Python25

9/23/2008  10:45 PM    <DIR>          .
9/23/2008  10:45 PM    <DIR>          ..
9/23/2008  10:45 PM    <DIR>          DLLs
9/23/2008  10:45 PM    <DIR>          Doc
9/23/2008  10:45 PM    <DIR>          include
9/25/2008  06:34 PM    <DIR>          Lib
9/23/2008  10:45 PM    <DIR>          libs
2/21/2008  01:05 PM            14,013 LICENSE.txt
2/21/2008  01:05 PM           119,048 NEWS.txt
2/21/2008  01:11 PM            24,064 python.exe
2/21/2008  01:12 PM            24,576 pythonw.exe
2/21/2008  01:05 PM            56,354 README.txt
9/23/2008  10:45 PM    <DIR>          tcl
9/23/2008  10:45 PM    <DIR>          Tools
2/21/2008  01:11 PM             4,608 w9xpopen.exe
          6 archivos        242,663 bytes
```

But it has ( the substitute I guess ) pydocgui...

```
C:\Python25>dir Tools\Scripts\pydocgui.pyw

10/28/2005  07:06 PM               222 pydocgui.pyw
           1 archivos            222 bytes
```

This launches a webserver and shows what I was looking for. All the modules plus all the classes that come with the platform.

The Doc dir contains the same as in:

http://docs.python.org/

Thanks a lot for guide me  to pydoc.

Answer (score 1):

> BTW I know that I would eventually
>   will read this:
>
> http://docs.python.org/lib/lib.html
>
> But, well, I think it is not today.

I suggest that you're making a mistake.  The lib doc has "the class, its methods and and example of how to use it."   It *is* what you are looking for.

I use both Java and Python all the time.  Dig into the library doc, you'll find everything you're looking for.

Comment: Yes I know. But when it comes to try to figure out what a method signature is, it is not very helpful to go en browse that file, go down , up etc. 

 I'm not saying I won't read it. It looks pretty interesting. But.. the day will come :P 

Thanks 1+ for you.

Comment: "it is not very helpful to go en browse that file, go down , up etc."  What?  What are you talking about?  It's a web site.  Bookmark it.

Comment: I'm talking that when looking for a method signature, scanning through the whole document is not at least for the the fastest way to get the answer. That's all.

Comment: I totally agree that searching is slow.  I use Google and bookmarks; they're fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the *environment variable* **PYTHONDOCS** to point to where the python documentation is installed.

On my system, it's in */usr/share/doc/python2.5*

So you can define this variable in your *shell profile* or somewhere else depending on your system:

> export PYTHONDOCS=/usr/share/doc/python2.5

Now, if you open an interractive python console, you can call the help system. For exemple:

> ```
> >>> help(Exception)
> >>> Help on class Exception in module exceptions:
>
> >>> class Exception(BaseException)
> >>>  |  Common base class for all non-exit exceptions.
> >>>  |  
> >>>  |  Method resolution order:
> >>>  |      Exception
> ```

Documentation is here:

https://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Windows [ActiveState Python](http://www.activestate.com/Products/activepython/index.mhtml) comes with the documentation, including the library reference in a searchable help file.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't directly answer your question (so I'll probably be downgraded), but you may be interested in [Jython](http://www.jython.org).

> Jython is an implementation of the high-level, dynamic, object-oriented language Python written in 100% Pure Java, and seamlessly integrated with the Java platform. It thus allows you to run Python on any Java platform.

Since you are coming from Java, Jython may help you leverage Python while still allowing you to use your Java knowledge.

Comment: It's ok. I tried Jython before. but since the Java api is there I'm just actually using java in some other language, which is fine, if what I need is integration. But in my case I'm looking for documentation on the Python platform itself. Pydoc is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also try

```
pydoc -p 11111
```

Then type in web browser http://localhost:11111

EDIT: of course you can use any other value for port number instead of 11111